# uWSGI + virtualenv 'No module named site'

Tags: virtualenv, uwsgi

So this seems to be a really common problem with this setup, but I can't find any solutions that work on SO. I've setup a very new Ubuntu 15.04 server, then installed nginx, virtualenv (and -wrapper), and uWSGI (via apt-get, so globally, not inside the virtualenv).

My virtualenv is located at `/root/Env/example`. Inside of the virtualenv, I installed Django, then at /srv/www/example/app ran Django's `startproject` command with the project name `example`, so I have vaguely this structure:

```
-root
  -Env
    -example
      -bin
      -lib
-srv 
  -www
    -example
      -app
        -example
          manage.py
          -example
            wsgi.py
            ...
```

My example.ini file for uWSGI looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
project = example

plugin = python

chdir = /srv/www/example/app/example
home = /root/Env/example
module = example.wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/app/example/example.socket
chmod-socket = 664
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
vacuum = true
```

But no matter whether I run this via `uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/example.ini` or via daemon, I get the exact same error:

```
Python version: 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:37:21)  [GCC 4.9.2]
Set PythonHome to /root/Env/example
ImportError: No module named site
```

I should note that the Django project works via the built-in development server `./manage.py runserver`, and that when I remove `home = /root/Env/example` the thing works (but is obviously using the global Python and Django rather than the virtualenv versions, which means it's useless for a proper virtualenv setup).

Can anyone see some obvious path error that I'm not seeing? As far as I can tell, `home` is entirely correct based on my directory structure, and everything else in the ini too, so why is it not working with this ImportError?

Comment: is this resolbved?

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I was seeing this issue because the django app I was trying to run was written in python 3 whereas uwsgi was configured for python 2. I fixed the problem by:

1. recompiling uwsgi to support both python 2 and python 3 apps 
   (I followed [this](https://bradenmacdonald.com/blog/2015/uwsgi-emperor-multiple-python) guide)
2. adding this to my mydjangoproject_uwsgi.ini:

```
plugins         = python35 # or whatever you specified while compiling uwsgi
```

For other folks using Django, you should also make sure you are correctly specifying the following:

```
# Django dir that contains manage.py
chdir           = /var/www/project/myprojectname
# Django wsgi (myprojectname is the name of your top-level project)
module          = myprojectname.wsgi:application
# the virtualenv you are using (full path)
home            = /home/ubuntu/Env/mydjangovenv
plugins         = python35
```

Answer (score -1):

As @Freek said, site refers to a python module.

The error claims that python cannot find that package, which is because you have specified python_home to the wrong location.

I've encountered with the same problem and my uwsgi.ini is like below:

```
[uwsgi]
# variable
base = /home/xx/
# project settings
chdir = %(base)/
module = botservice.uwsgi:application
home = %(base)/env/bin
```

For this configuration uwsgi can find python executable in /env/bin but no packages could be found under this folder. So I changed home to

```
home = %(base)/env/
```

and it worked for me.

In your case, I suggest digging into `home` directive and point it to a location which contains both python executable and packages.

Answer (score -5):

The `site` module is in the root of django.

First check is to activate the virtualenv manually (`source /root/Env/example/bin/activate`, start python and `import site`). If that fails, pip install django.

Assuming that django is correctly installed in the virtualenv, make sure that uWSGI activates the virtualenv. Relevant uWSGI configuration directives:

```
plugins = python
virtualenv = /root/Env/example
```

and in case you have error importing `example.wsgi`:

```
pythonpath = /srv/www/example/app/example
```