# uwsgi plugin "python3" works with Python 3.6 and not with Python3.8

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, uwsgi, python-3.8

I have the following `uwsgi` config:

```
[uwsgi]
callable=app
mount = /labs=/home/vinzee/projectname/app/wsgi.py
manage-script-name = true
touch-reload=/home/vinzee/projectname/app/wsgi.py
socket=/tmp/labshome.sock
processes=5
threads=1
venv=/home/vinzee/.virtualenvs/projectnamevenv38
chdir=/home/vinzee/projectname/app/
plugin=logfile,python3
logger=delete file:/dev/null/c.log
log-route = delete (\] POST \/save => generated )
pythonpath=/home/vinzee/projectname/
```

The virtual environment specified in `venv` uses `Python3.8`. And when reloading `uwsgi`, I get the classic error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

The same error happens when `uwsgi`'s plugin is `python` and the project uses Python >= 3, as can be seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45965969/5446749).

When I switch to Python3.6, the `ModuleNotFoundError` disappears and everything works properly.
I already have the package `uwsgi-plugin-python3` to the latest version.

How can I get rid of this error for `Python3.8`? What package do I need to install?

Comment: Hi, Did you find the solution. I am stuck in the same problem now?

Comment: I think I did, but I am not sure. The virtualenv uses Python3.8 and my Ubuntu has a default Python of 3.6. On my new computer, I have a default Python version of 3.8 and the virtualenv has also 3.8 and it works. It seems to me that the virtualenv needs to have the same version than the default Python3 on the machine.

Comment: Alright, I also checked, I have both python3.6 and python 3.8 available on my server. For me also, python 3.6 was the default one. I alias it in the `~/.bashrc` file and now If I tried `python3 --version`, it outputs the `python3.8`. My venv is also python3.8. But I think I am missing something. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There was bytecode change in Py3.8 and would require uWSGI to support it which it currently does not unfortunately. I have been tracking this for a while and have yet to see any major updates.

Comment: Facing a similar issue with uWSGI not working with rh-python38

`   compilation terminated.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> uWSGI

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a problem of creating a virtual environment.

```
virtualenv flask

cd flask

source bin/activate    (for activate env )
```

also you can try to add your python path in wsgi file config

```
sys.path.append('/home/deployer/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
```

or

```
export PYTHONPATH=/root/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

finally.. run :

```
python -m flask run
```